# Community Builder - recordID - VisualForce Page

Tags: visualforce, community

From communities, I am inserting a VisualForce page to show a custom object linked to an Account object.  I want to show the account information and then drill down to show the custom object details.  I've bound my VisualForce page with the Account standard Controller:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" docType="html" showheader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
        <apex:define name="body">
           <body>
                <h1>
                    <b>My Products for {!account.name}</b>
               </h1>
            </body>     
        </apex:define>
</apex:page>
```

According to the documentation, the recordID is resolved to an object based on context.  I assumed that resolves to Account.  It appears it doesn't.

[image]

What Salesforce object(s) does the recordID resolve to from Community?  Should I use the StandardController to reference that object?

Answer (score 0):

I had to place my custom VisualForce page on the Account Detail object page in order for it to resolve the Account object in my custom VisualForce page.

I would rather have a the custom page independent of the Account Detail page.